# longest common subsequence of bigger strings?

Tags: c++

if the each of the strings length is greater than 60000 then i tried by using two array because i couldn't declare an array of like dp[60000][60000]..so that's why i tried like that but the time limit exceeded...how to do for the longer srings..is there any way within time like 3 or 5 sec?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstring>
#include<string.h>
#include<algorithm>
using namespace std;
const int size=50000;
int dp_x[size+1],dp_xp1[size+1];
char a[size+1],b[size+1];
int lcs()
{
    int strlena=strlen(a);
    int strlenb=strlen(b);
    for(int y=0;y<=strlenb;y++)
        dp_x[y]=0;
    for(int x=strlena-1;x>=0;x--)
    {
        memcpy(dp_xp1,dp_x,sizeof(dp_x));
        dp_x[strlenb]=0;
        for(int y=strlenb-1;y>=0;y--)
        {
            if(a[x]==b[y])
                dp_x[y]=1+dp_xp1[y+1];
            else
                dp_x[y]=max(dp_xp1[y],dp_x[y+1]);
        }
    }
    return dp_x[0];
}
int main()
{
    while(gets(a)&&gets(b))
    {
        int ret=lcs();
        cout<<ret<<endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd imagine that a 60000x60000 array would consume a lot of memory

Comment: Please, please, please **format your code**. Thanks

Comment: `stlen()` just iterates over the char array to find the first null character. So if performance (time) its your goal, using `strlen()` is not a good approach, also considering the length of your strings.

Comment: In addition, your code its C, no C++. Using stdstreams for output doesn't means that you are "programming in C++". **You are programming  in C with a C++ compiler**

Comment: @Manu343726 I didn't know that you could use `cout<<ret<<endl;` in c

Comment: @SamIam I suppose it might be a matter of perspective on todays systems with hundreds of GB of memory, but in my mind there's nothing imaginative about 3.6GB being a lot of memory...

Comment: @SamIam have you readed my comment fine? **He is programming as if he was using C, with a C++ compiler which allows him to use C++ output streams**. But thats not C++ at all!!!

Comment: @twalberg you mean hundreds of GB of disk space right?

Comment: @SamIam No, I mean hundreds of GB of RAM. Of course, that's not your typical home system, but I routinely deal with server systems that have quite a lot of memory (e.g. 32 cores and 384GB of RAM)...

Comment: @Manu343726 If a conformant C++ parser and compiler accepts it, it is technically C++. It may not be very good C++, as it's essentially "the subset of C++ that is compatible with C", but according to relevant standards, it is still C++.

Comment: @twalberg I don't think user2739256 routinely deals with servers with 32 cores and 384GB of RAM. I know I don't.

Comment: @twalberg thats not the point. The point is, even a C++ compiler accepts a subset of the C++ language that its compatible, almost identical, to the C programming language; **C and C++ are very different languages**. If OP asks about a C problem, I suggest him a C solution. If he ask about C++, I suggest a C++ solution. **This question is really a C question tagged as C++. The proof is that I cant provide a C++ solution, because the problems of the question are not related with C++ at all, are related with C mechanisms/libraries**

Comment: To reduce the complexity, there are some good references at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence_problem

Comment: Another reference: http://simplygenius.net/Article/DiffTutorial1

Comment: @twalberg Even on such systems, you don't want to create huge working sets if you don't have to. Memory is slow, so the tighter you can pack your data, the better. I recently read some research papers that were proposing to compress data in RAM, not to save space, but because decompressing to the L1 cache can be *faster* than `memcpy`.

Answer (score 1):

In each iteration, you're `memcpy`'ing a row. That takes O(n) time per iteration, so O(n²) time in total. Replace the `memcpy` by a pointer swap. So, instead of working on `dp_x` and `dp_x1` directly, use two pointers, initially:

```
int *current = dp_x, previous = dp_x1;
```

Then, inside your loop, replace the copy with a swap:

```
std::swap(current, previous);
```

Comment: is there any fruitfull algorithm for this??

Comment: @user2739256: I don't understand that question.

Comment: plz can anyone do the pointer swap instead of memcpy in my code above??